Firebase is not connecting locally
I have a React application and I use firebase for authentication, database and storage. I had to update the firebase version, because from my old version, we can't logging using the Google option anymore.
I updated to the current last firebase version: ^10.12.2 and I solved the authentication part, but it brokes other parts of the code.
I think that the code works well, but for some reason when I try to get or set a document to my local firebase, I can't and it doesn't show any log in the firebaseEmulator.
I can see the new user on the emulator, but not any log. I just can see warnings in the browser console:

@firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.12.2): WebChannelConnection RPC 'Write' stream 0x4e810535 transport errored: > Object { type: "c", target: {…}, g: {…}, defaultPrevented: false, status: 1 }

This is my configuration:
// clientApp.js
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAuth, connectAuthEmulator } from 'firebase/auth';
import { getFirestore, connectFirestoreEmulator } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { getStorage, connectStorageEmulator } from 'firebase/storage';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: ...,
  authDomain: ...,
  projectId: ...,
  storageBucket: ...,
  messagingSenderId: ...,
  appId: ...,
  measurementId: ...,
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const auth = getAuth(app);
export const firestore = getFirestore(app);
export const storage = getStorage(app);

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  connectAuthEmulator(auth, 'http://localhost:9099');
  connectFirestoreEmulator(firestore, 'localhost', 8080);
  connectStorageEmulator(storage, 'localhost', 9199);
}

And I use it like this:
import { firestore } from "../firebase/clientApp";
import { collection, query, where, getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore';

const [secretKey, setSecretKey] = useState([]);
const [compras, setCompras] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    const loadData = async () => {
      const userCollection = collection(firestore, 'users');
      const userQuery = query(userCollection, where('email', '==', user.email));
      const userData = await getDocs(userQuery);

      console.log('user', userData.docs);

      const comprasCollection = collection(firestore, 'compras');
      const comprasQuery = query(
        comprasCollection,
        where('userId', '==', user.uid),
        where('esReal', '==', true),
        where('createdAt', '>=', date)
      );
      const comprasData = await getDocs(comprasQuery);

      console.log('compras', comprasData.docs);

      setSecretKey(userData.docs);
      setCompras(comprasData.docs);

      setLoading(false);
    };

    loadData()
      .then(() => {
        console.log('Data loaded');
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  }, [])

I don't know where is trying to retreive the data but I don't get any error and it retreives and empty array.
Like I said I don't know where is firebase pointing, but is not my emulator, maybe is pointing to the cloud or somewhere else.

Can you prove that process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' when you run this? Perhaps by logging something or doing some step-through debugging that shows the code is definitely trying to connect to the emulator?

Added more code in the second part. The first 2 logs return an empty array even if I create a document manually. The last log return the Data loaded string.
Also I put a log inside of the if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') to see if it is true and yes, I am in development environment. @DougStevenson
